# Decorator inside a class throw warning in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, decorator, python-3.6

I am using **PyCharm IDE** and below is a fragment of code where I am using a decorator. The decorator is basically checking whether the argument `extract` is an integer >= 0.
This code is working as far as I can tell however I noticed some syntax error in PyCharm.

```
class MyClass(object):    
    def _argument_test_extract(func):
        def _helper(*args, **kwargs):
            kwargs = inspect.getcallargs(func, *args, **kwargs)
            if 'rule' in kwargs:
                extract = kwargs['rule']['extract']
                if type(extract) == int and extract >= 0:
                    return func(**kwargs)
                else:
                    raise Exception("Argument `extract` is not an integer")
        return _helper

    @_argument_test_extract
    def _perform_split_model_string(self, rule):
        # do some stuff
```

PyCharm indicates the following message for the line where I decorate the function with `@_argument_test_extract`:

> > Function '_argument_test_extract' lacks a positional argument

The line where the decorator function is defined `def _argument_test_extract(func):` indicates the following message

> > Usually first parameter of a function is 'self'

Finally the line `return func(**kwargs)` indicates the following message:

> > 'MyClass' is not callable

Obviously, if I decorate the function `_argument_test_extract` with `@staticmethod` all the warning of PyCharm disappear but the code is not working anymore because of this error, `TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable`.

Is there something wrong with my syntax? Thanks

Comment: Why is the decorator inside the class? Just move it outside, as a standard function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there something wrong with my syntax

well ... if it works, apparently not :-).  There's probably something wrong with pycharm's static analysis.

With *that* said, there *is* something weird about what you're doing.  PyCharm is noticing that (after class creation), `_argument_test_abstract` is going to become a method of the class.  As a method of the class, `_argument_test_abstract` will require an argument.  However, during class creation, `_argument_test_abstract` isn't yet a method and this is when the decoration occurs -- So it works.  (as you've noted, `@staticmethod` doesn't solve the problem because the `staticmethod` descriptor itself isn't callable, only the function that it returns from `__get__`).

So, where does that leave us?  You can continue with what you have and just ignore pycharm, or you can move the decorator out of the class and make it module level.  It really doesn't need to be in the class in the first place :-).  I would argue that moving it out of the class is the better solution because lots of people reading your code are going to wonder where `self` is and how this whole thing doesn't blow up every time you try to execute it, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great explanation, I will move the decorator out the class.

Comment: I would hope PyCharm suggest such option more clearly.